# A "conjecture on" or a "conjecture about"?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

As a non-English scientist, the question bothers me. Maybe the answer depends on the context? Allow me to give a few examples. These are titles of a short text:

1. Is it better to say "A conjecture on the inner mechanisms of cells" or
   "A conjecture about the inner mechanisms of cells"?
2. Is it better to say "A conjecture on the working of enzyme XYZ" or
   "A conjecture about the working of enzyme XYZ"?
3. Is it better to say "A conjecture on the structure of DNA" or
   "A conjecture about the structure of DNA"?
4. Is it better to say "A conjecture on deducing the molecular structure" or
   "A conjecture about deducing the molecular structure"?
5. Is it better to say "A conjecture on the origin of chirality" or
   "A conjecture about the origin of chirality"?

For those who do not believe it: Google gives only a few pages of hits when searching for the two expressions ("A conjecture about": 13 pages; "A conjecture on": 7 pages). The number is so small that no conclusion can be drawn. Also there seems to be no discussion of the issue anywhere on the web.

Update: For usage statistics, look at https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+conjecture+concerning%2Ca+conjecture+respecting%2Ca+conjecture+regarding%2Ca+conjecture+on%2Ca+conjecture+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20conjecture%20concerning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20conjecture%20respecting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20conjecture%20regarding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20conjecture%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20conjecture%20about%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20conjecture%20concerning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20conjecture%20respecting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20conjecture%20regarding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20conjecture%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20conjecture%20about%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Hello, Johannes. A reasonable amount of research is expected to be given with questions. Here, Google ngrams for _a conjecture on_ and _a conjecture about_ probably indicate an overarching switch in choice of preposition. But for individual examples, you can Google them directly to check on favoured forms.

Comment: [This usage NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+conjecture+concerning%2Ca+conjecture+respecting&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20conjecture%20concerning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20conjecture%20respecting%3B%2Cc0) surprised me a bit. Apparently a couple of centuries ago, *a conjecture **respecting** [whatever it was about]* was actually more common than *a conjecture **concerning** [its subject matter]*. But today, ***about*** is by far the most common preposition for the context.

Comment: @Edwin: see edit.

Comment: The prepositions sound like they are more closely tied to the later words than to *conjecture*.

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, this might be so; can you try to give your favorites? As I said, I am not a native speaker, so I have no reliable feeling for this. That is the reason I gave several examples.

Comment: Try substituting other (noun forms of) verbs of thinking - e.g. *thought, guess, hypothesis*, etc. Prepositions convey intent, so which preposition you use depends on what you want to express. Without knowing the intent, we pretty much fall back to the lower bar of grammaticality, which isn't very useful at this level. By way of analogy - should a green patch be painted next to a blue or yellow patch? Or perhaps red or maybe black might be better? It depends on what effect you want to convey. Likewise with prepositions.

Comment: In other words, picking a preposition expresses an intent - and since we don't know your intent, we can't pick the preposition for you.

Comment: *Conjecture* is not normally used with an article, nor is it often followed by a preposition—at least not in the way you're trying to do it. What is your whole sentence? Expand the examples [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/conjecture) to see typical usage. You might be looking for something like this: *His idea of the inner mechanisms of cells was conjecture.* Or this: *His ideas included a lot of conjecture about the structure of DNA.*

Comment: As a noun, conjecture **about** x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use (1) on (2) on/about (3) on (4) Conjectures on the deduction of the molecular structure of DNA (5) on.

If you look at [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conjecture#examples)'s example sentences, you'll see they mainly use the noun 'conjecture' without a prepositional phrase. The exceptions are

- The biography includes conjectures about the writer's earliest ambitions.
- a conjecture about the extent of the injury

But these are not addressing fundamental issues (the inner mechanisms of cells / the structure of DNA / the origin of chirality). I'd prefer to use 'on', echoing 'on the subject of' and 'A Theorem on Boolean Matrices' [[R T Prosser, ATM](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/321105.321107)] say. Neither preposition is incorrect here, but 'a conjecture on' is more formal, more in an academic register.

Comment: Thank you - the last sentence sums it up well, I think. Also the NGram reflects this.

Answer (score 1):

Neither seems natural English to me.  If one wishes to write elegant scientific English (and “conjecture” suggests the poster might) I suggest:

“A conjecture **regarding**…”

A matter of taste, but I think my answer tastes better than the accepted one.

Comment: Indeed, also elegant.